# Can not find data types in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql

I am trying to create a database table using PostgreSQL but I am unable to find the data types that are mentioned in the schema. Please help me out. Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AUTO_INCREMENT` sounds like `mysql` type. You want to use `serial` in `postgresql` for the same purpose.

```
CREATE TABLE tz_todo (
    "id" serial primary key,
    position bigint,
    "text" varchar(255),
    dt_added timestamp
);
```